# set alpha channel for pyplot objects?

Tags: matplotlib

In R, you can set the alpha channel by

```
rgb(r=.1,g=.5,b=.5,alpha=.5,max=1)
```

for any object that takes a color argument. `patch` objects in pyplot have a `set_alpha` method, but can this be done for lines on a plot, for instance? like `pyplot.plot(x,y,color=???)` or `h = pyplot.plot(x,y)` and do something with `h`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`plt.plot(x,y,'ro-',alpha=0.3)`

if you want to mix up your own color, you can pass a hex value or an rgb tuple http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/colors_api.html

Answer (score 3):

Appears that

```
h = plt.plot(x,y)
```

returns a list of `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` objects in `h` even if there is one element plotted, so `h[0].set_alpha()` is the method to use.